# Android layouts: fit View under Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the action bar as a translucent overlay (like the Google Earth app), using:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

All my Views of full-screen height now extend beneath the action bar, but I only want one of them to do that. So my question is, is there a way to automatically fit Views so that they do not extend underneath the action bar overlay? I'd rather not have to use a custom dp setting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fit the views automatically since action bar is in overlay mode. You need to set action bar height as marginTop for the view. You can refer the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#TopMargin)